# How to print the file names to the console when clicking their buttons?

Tags: python, tkinter

At the below example, the buttons are created according to the files in a spesific directory. And i added a print function to the buttons. What i wanted to do is, when i click each button, every button should print the related file. But according to the below codes, when i click every button, they print the same file name which is the last item of the file list. Can you help me to show me what's missing in these codes?

```
from tkinter import *
import os


class Application:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = Tk()

        self.frame = Frame()
        self.frame.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.widgets()
        self.mainloop = self.window.mainloop()

    def widgets(self):
        files = self.path_operations()
        for i in range(len(files)):
            button = Button(self.frame, text="button{}".format(i))
            button.grid(row=0, column=i)
            button.configure(command=lambda: print(files[i]))

    @staticmethod
    def path_operations():
        path = "D:\TCK\\Notlar\İş Başvurusu Belgeleri"
        file_list = [i for i in os.listdir(path) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, i))]
        return file_list


a = Application()
```

Comment: Oh, thank you, i will look at that page.

Answer (score 1):

The program needs somehow to know what file to print, but `i` is shared and changes. Here's a technique:

```
def widgets(self):
    files = self.path_operations()
    for i in range(len(files)):
        button = Button(self.frame, text="button{}".format(i))
        button.grid(row=0, column=i)
        button.configure(command=self.make_print(files[i]))

@staticmethod
def make_print(file):
    def local_print ():
        print(file)
    return local_print
```

Comment: This technique solved my problem. Thank you very much.